# How can i change due date of invoice after the validation

Tags: odoo-9

I want to change some fields after the validation of the invoice when i do a payment (mostly i need it for the due date) in a way that due date takes the payment date when a i have a partial payment in order to know all the due date . Should i create a new function or i override a function that already exist ?Any idea for help please ?